# Commutator subgroup of matrices of order two!

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Let $G$ be the group of all invertible matrices on the real field of order two under multiplication. And define $N=\{X\in G:det(X)=1\}$, prove that $N=G'$.
That's easy to prove that $G'\subset N$ using simple properties of determinant!
**The main part of solution is to prove that $N\subset G'$**

---

Note that $G'$ Denotes the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Comment: When discussing groups of matrices, you need to specify the field. Also, you probably mean degree two rather than order two.

Comment: A solution can be found at many places, e.g., [here](https://twoplusonet.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/commutator-subgroup-of-glnr/).

Comment: The set of invertible matrices of order 2 is not a group in general. For example, the general linear group has a subgroup isomorphic to the symmetric group, which is generated by elements of order 2 but contains elements that have order different from 2.

Comment: @MattSamuel I expect the question is referring to $2 \times 2$ matrices, not matrices of order $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You generate $G'$ by *transductions*, i.e., shear maps.

If that is not enough, see Theorem 8.8 in this [file](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Ewebb/oldteaching/Year2010-11/LinearGroups.pdf).